# Перевод double в String^ в двоичной системе счисления c++

Tags: c++-cli, типы, системы-счисления

Пишу калькулятор на c++, считываю данные из TextBox, затем преобразую их в std::string, а после через stold преобразую в double. Теперь столкнулся с задачей перевода чисел из одной СС в другую. Нашёл функцию, которая преобразует std::string в double с определённым основанием СС, но не могу придумать, как переводить double в String^ в нужной мне СС (пока только двоичная).
Прошу помочь мне с этой проблемой, потому что только она отделяет меня от написания полноценного калькулятора.

Comment: ```doubleVariable.ToString()``` возвращает ваш String^

Comment: Запомните: C++ и C++/CLI - это **разные** языки. Вам C++/CLI сейчас не нужен, я это гарантирую. Если хотите гуевое приложение на WinForms, возьмите язык C#. Если хотите учить чистый C++ - забудьте пока про GUI. А лучше вообще на время откажитесь от Visual Studio.

Comment: У меня задача стоит написать калькулятор именно на C++